# Rebol: Found a way to auto-generate and execute code dynamically, is there a better way?

Tags: rebol

I have experimented with this:

```
>> code-block: copy []
== []
>> append code-block [func[][print "a"] ]
== [func [] [print "a"]]
>> do do code-block
a
>>
```

Is there a way to avoid to do "do" twice :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you have put into **code-block** is not the function, but the source of the function, hence the need to **do** it once to make a function, then **do** it again as a function.

You can see that like this:

```
length? code-block
== 3
```

To just put the function in **code-block**, can do this:

```
code-block: copy []
append code-block func[][print "a"]    ;; no block around the FUNC
```

Or this:

```
code-block: copy []
append code-block reduce [func[][print "a"] ]  ;; use REDUCE to evaluate the block
```

Either way, what is in **code-block** is now just the function:

```
length? code-block
== 1
type? first code-block
== function!
do code-block     ;; what you asked for!
a
```

Comment: Doesn't reduce play the same role as the second do in fact ?

Comment: In effect, yes. But it happens only once: when the block is created; not every time when the code in the block is executed. So it should be faster overall.